# Convert normal links to Ajax dynamically

Tags: ajax, dynamic, load, hyperlink

I have put together some code from various sources but javascript is somewhat unknown to me and I only seem to fail with the code I have so far..

What I want to do is convert every normal link on the page to ajax links and load the pages through ajax.

So far I only succeeded to transform the links from the initial page and load the content in a div. The problem is I don't have access to the content is loading in the div and the new content still has normal links instead of ajax.

- Is there a way I can convert the new links within the content loaded in the div, every time the div changes?
- Also what I don't know is, if the user clicks on the home button in the menu, it will load the content of index along with this script, and everything will become a loop. How can I prevent the code from loading in index if it loads inside the div?
- If you suspect any other problems it may occur from this code can you please advice me what to change?

This is the code I have so far..
Thank you very much for any advice!

**Inserted in the head tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else if(window.ActiveXObject){ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
else{ }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{ document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
else{ document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = ""; }
}

function loadPage(url){
document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = "";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

**Inserted somewhere in the body:**

```
<div id="contentarea"></div>
```

**Inserted right before the body ends:**

```
<script>
var oP = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var ctr=0;
while(ctr < oP.length){
var oldHref = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[ctr].href;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[ctr].href="javascript:loadPage('"+oldHref+"');";
ctr++;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here ja go.. whipped this up for you.. you can use document.links to get all anchor tags. I'm doing this on 'contentArea' only. Everything inside (function () { will only be called when the document is ready. Then, in the onreadystatechange event I call the function again to set the click event on any anchors that are returned in the resposne.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;

function loadPage(url){
document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = "";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

var parseAnchors = function(){
    var anchors = document.getElementById("contentarea").links; // your anchor collection
    var i = anchors.length;
    while (i--) {
      var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.onclick = (function(url) {
          return function() {
            loadPage(url);
            return false;
          };
        })(anchors[i].href);
        anchor.href = "#";
    }
  };

(function () {

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
   else if(window.ActiveXObject){ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
   else{ }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
   { document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
   else{ document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML = ""; }
   parseAnchors();
 }

window.onload = function () {
 parseAnchors();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code has not been tested. I want to give you the general idea of what you should be doing. Also I just noticed your question about the loop. Well, it sounds strange what you are doing, but my solution of only setting the ajax click handler on the links inside the content area should save you. Try it out and give some feedback on the results.

Comment: Thanks but is not working.. I tried many things since I asked but I returned to my original code and of course to the same problems.. Can you suggest something else?